# Javascript Form Select Change Options Dynamic List/ one to multiple lists

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

trying to make one Select change option control multiple select options. Select the first option where following options are associated with choices for first option. I entered the third line but the second line does not work and the third line receives the select the the two would.

```
<script>
function populate(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    var s3 = document.getElementByis(s3);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    s3.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
        var optionArray = ["|","camaro|Camaro","corvette|Corvette","impala|Impala"];
    } else if(s1.value == "Dodge"){
        var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
    } else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
        var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
        s3.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
<hr />
Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2','slct3')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select>
<hr />
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
<hr />
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct3" name="slct3"></select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looks that there are some typos in your code.

```
function populate(s1,s2){ //missing parameter 's3'
...
  var s3 = document.getElementByis(s3) //Should be getElementById
...
```

Given that to append the new option node you created inside your `for` loop, you should use the [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) function. But since you can't append the same node twice in your DOM, you can use the [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) function.

Then you replace the lines:

```
...
s2.options.add(newOption);
s3.options.add(newOption);
...
```

With:

```
...
var dup = newOption.cloneNode(true);  // check the docs for the 'true' parameter here
s2.appendChild(newOption);
s3.appendChild(dup);
...
```

Working Fiddle:

```html
<script>
function populate(s1,s2,s3){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    var s3 = document.getElementById(s3);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    s3.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
        var optionArray = ["|","camaro|Camaro","corvette|Corvette","impala|Impala"];
    } else if(s1.value == "Dodge"){
        var optionArray = ["|","avenger|Avenger","challenger|Challenger","charger|Charger"];
    } else if(s1.value == "Ford"){
        var optionArray = ["|","mustang|Mustang","shelby|Shelby"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        var dup = newOption.cloneNode(true);
        s2.appendChild(newOption);
        s3.appendChild(dup);
        // s2.options.add(newOption);
        // s3.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
<hr />
Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2','slct3')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select>
<hr />
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
<hr />
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct3" name="slct3"></select>
</body>
```

Comment: how do I accept it  is there a button that I need to click to accept it?

Comment: if I wanted to create a second array that was dependent on the value from s1.value. If that Possible? can I have two arrays dependent one variable

Comment: @VinBro Sure you can, just add the proper logic, there should be no problem at all.

Comment: can I send you the code that I was trying to use? I have searched for an answer but nothing fits. Second, where did you learn to write functions and how can I do it?

Comment: @VinBro Sure you could send me the code, but I think it would be better figuring it out by yourself. You seem to be lacking some basic notions. Look for some tutorial in the basics first. After that, you can always elaborate another question here in Stack Overflow =)